# print() function! Error 4096 object could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter, printf

I have a variable called **$result** which should store all the results from my database query however when I run print ($result) it gives an error message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to
>   string
>
> Filename: models/control_panel_model.php
>
> Line Number: 72

Here is my model code:

```
public function view_record($record_id)
        {
            $criteria = array 
            (
                'procedure_id' => $record_id
            );

            echo $this->db->count_all('procedure');
            return;
            $this->db->select('procedure.procedure_id, procedure.patient_id, procedure.department_id, procedure.name_id , procedure.dosage_id');
            $this->db->from ('procedure');

            $this->db->join('patient', 'patient.patient_id = procedure.patient_id', 'inner');
            $this->db->join('department', 'department.department_id = procedure.department_id', 'inner');
            $this->db->join('procedure_name', 'procedure_name.procedure_name_id = procedure.name_id', 'inner');
            $this->db->join('dosage', 'dosage.dosage_id = procedure.dosage_id', 'inner');

            $this->db->where('procedure_id', $record_id);
            $result = $this->db->get();


            print($result);


            return ;


        }
```

The reason I am using a print function is just to test if my query is working and it has values. How do I achieve this.

Thanks

EDIT!!!

Here is what I get in var_dump();

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#22 (8) { 
  ["conn_id"]=> resource(30) of type (mysql link persistent)
  ["result_id"]=> resource(40) of type (mysql result)
  ["result_array"]=> array(0) { }
  ["result_object"]=> array(0) { }
  ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { }
  ["current_row"]=> int(0)
  ["num_rows"]=> int(0) 
  ["row_data"]=> NULL
}
```

I HAVE ADDED THE FOLLOWING CODE:

> if ($result->num_rows >0)             {
>                 echo "Data";
>                             }
>                         else            {
>                 echo "No Data";
>                         }

IT IS SAYING THERE IS **"NO DATA"** so my query must be crap and wrong , so I need to redesign query. THERE IS DATA IN MY DATABASE SO must be query

===========================================

Here is my schema
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSHSQ.png

[image]

Comment: Thanks however it is returning all this: object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#22 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(30) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(40) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["row_data"]=> NULL } 

Is this my query result?

Comment: @sqlmole: Please add the var_dump output to your question, not as a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object in question (`CI_DB_mysql_result`) is missing the [`__toString` implementation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) that's why you get the error.

However, this can mean that the object can not be usefully converted to string.

Instead you should convert the objects data to string first on your own for the purpose of your `print` operation. I can not say from the code you've posted which use you're looking for specifically, so there is not more I can add to this.

Please see [Generating Query Results](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) and [Active Record Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

**Edit:** For a quick and dirty string-printing, you can use `print_r`, however I do not know if this is actually helpful for your case:

```
$result = $this->db->get();
print_r($result);
```

That's comparable to the suggestion given to use `var_dump`. You should say which kind of information you would like to print actually and for this you should know the type of data the database returns. See the documentation of [`get()`<sup>*Active Record Class*</sup>](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) for some examples how to work with the return values.

Comment: Thanks I have dumped the result of var_dump in the question

Comment: @sqlmole: As your `var_dump` shows (please paste it formatted next time) the result is empty. So even if you would convert it into a string, it's an empty one. You're probably not understanding what the functions you're using are for and/or are doing. Check the data in your database as well to find out which values you would like to return (if any). I suggest you read the CI documentation, it's with examples and quite well explained. This should give you the information you need to go on.

Comment: I HAVE BEEN FOLLOWING THE CI EXAMPLES !!!!!! THEY ARE NOT WELL EXPLAINED !!!!! HELP ME PLEASE

Comment: @sqlmole: Calm down first, get 30 minutes on the fresh air outside and drink a tea. You're just missing a little link from what I see. And I don't see a print example in the docs. It's just a foreach on `$result` from `get()`. With a little patience you're mostly better able to understand, just don't feel offended if I have pointed to the docs. It's with the best intentions. Just help me to help you.

Comment: I have added new code to model it is saying there is no row returned so my query must be wrong. Thanks

Comment: I accepted your answer although you do not understand. I am trying to make function that retrieves record data that a user has added to database. So if you user sumbits record id = "1" the function will retirieve all rows matching that and join them

Comment: @sqlmole: You should ask your next question more concrete, like "how can I join across multiple tables with CodeIgniter Active Record". And then explain that you've build a query that does not return the data you expected. However all this was not part of your question here so I could not see your problem. Always imagine that users here who read your questions have a different background and can't read your mind. Doing some little-role-play will help you to get better answers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function **result_array()** that returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced:

```
...
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
print($result);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The get() method does not return a result. Try changing your query and $result-lines to something like this

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('procedure_id', $record_id);
$result = $this->db->result();
```

Comment: Thanks but it is now saying **Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\midas\application\models\control_panel_model.php on line 70**

Comment: @sqlmole: You're using the [Active Record Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), it does not have the `result()` method. Use a method instead that works for you, like [`get()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select), however, process the return value into a string before you print it. See my answer below.

Comment: Ok I changed back to get() and have posted the results of the query in the question

Answer (score 0):

num_rows is a method, not a property.